# Math riddle about 4 cups

Tags: puzzle

There are 4 cups filled till half. In 2 cups there are  one drink and in other 2 another drink. They are placed randomly on a table. How to drink half cup of each drink?

Comment: "How to drink one cup of each drink"? Just drink all of them! Actually, you need only drink three of the four cups, if you want to optimize this.

Comment: You have to drink exactly a cup of both drinks

Comment: What you describe is this: 2 cups half full of drink A = 1 full cup of drink A, 2 cups half full of drink B = 1 full cup of drink B. So, in total there is precisely 1 full cup of each drink, so drink everything, as Matti said. Otherwise, it is not clear what you are asking, please think some more about it and then edit you question.

Comment: Non-mathematical puzzles are far more welcome on the Puzzling SE.

Comment: Yeah, I meant drink half of each drink

Comment: It's likely that you need to mix drinks in a way so that you are guaranteed to get one full cup of mixed drinks in the ratio 1:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't know how to solve the problem in finitely many steps.*

Label drinks as $A$ and $B$, and the cups as $1,\, 2,\, 3,\, 4.$ Then we have six possible starting positions, but we can just look at three cases due to the symmetry of the problem (just exchange $A$ and $B$).

I will represent this in a table writing a fraction of a cup each drink occupies at a given step. Steps will always consist of pouring from a full cup to a half full cup until the half full one becomes full, the only exception being the first step. This is because I assume that we do not have the ability to measure a half of rhe content of a cup, so if at any point we get two full and two empty cups, we are stuck.

\begin{array}{ c | c | c  c  c  c | c  c  c  c | c  c  c  c }
\text{Drink} & \text{Step} & \text{Case}\, 1 & & & & \text{Case}\, 2 & & & & \text{Case}\, 3 & & & &\\ 
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
A & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   \\ \hline
\end{array}

The steps will be the following: pour from $1$ to $2$, pour from $2$ to $3$, pour from $3$ to $2$, pour from $2$ to $3$, and so on. We will make some conclusions after observing what happens after couple of steps:

\begin{array}{ c | c | c  c  c  c | c  c  c  c | c  c  c  c }
\text{Drink} & \text{Step} & \text{Case}\, 1 & & & & \text{Case}\, 2 & & & & \text{Case}\, 3 & & & &\\ 
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
A & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   \\ \hline
A & 1 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   \\ \hline
A & 2 & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/4 & 3/4 & 0   & 0   & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/4 & 3/4 & 0   \\ \hline
A & 3 & 0   & 3/4 & 1/4 & 0   & 0   & 5/8 & 3/8 & 0   & 0   & 3/8 & 1/8 & 1/2 \\
B &   & 0   & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 0   & 3/8 & 1/8 & 1/2 & 0   & 5/8 & 3/8 & 0   \\ \hline
A & 4 & 0   & 3/8 & 5/8 & 0   &     \\
B &   & 0   & 1/8 & 3/8 & 1/2 &     \\ \hline
\end{array}

First notice that Cases $2$ and $3$ became essentially the same after first step (just exchange $A$ and $B$). That's why we won't concern ourselves with Case $3$ anymore.

Also, I purposely didn't include step $4$ for Cases $2$ and $3$ because I want you to notice that Case $1$ is essentially the same as Cases $2$ and $3$, but *one step behind*. This tells us something important: if we can solve the problem in $n$ steps for Cases $2$ and $3$, it will be solved in $(n+1)$-st step for Case $1$. Since we do not know in which case we are, we can't solve the problem in finitely many steps using this process! That's why we will introduce a sequence $(a_n)$ which will tell us the fraction of Drink $A$ in the full cup at particular step. This sequence obeys recurrence relation $a_{n+2} = \frac 12 a_{n+1} + \frac 12 a_n$, which will hopefully be explained by the table:

\begin{array}{ c | c | c  c  c  c | c  c  c  c}
\text{Drink} & \text{Step} & \text{Case}\, 1 & & & & \text{Case}\, 2 & & & & \\ 
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
A & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0    \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2 & 0   & 1/2  \\ \hline
A & 1 & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & a_0 & 1/2 & 0    \\
B &   & 0   & 0   & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1-a_0 & 0   & 1/2 \\ \hline
A & 2 & 0   & 1/2   & a_0       & 0   & 0   & a_0/2     & a_1   & 0   \\
B &   & 0   & 0     & 1-a_0     & 1/2 & 0   & (1-a_0)/2 & 1-a_1 & 1/2 \\ \hline
A & 3 & 0   & a_1   & a_0/2     & 0   & 0   & a_2   & a_1/2     & 0   \\
B &   & 0   & 1-a_1 & (1-a_0)/2 & 1/2 & 0   & 1-a_2 & (1-a_1)/2 & 1/2 \\ \hline
A & 4 & 0   & a_1/2     & \small{a_2 = a_0/2 + a_1/2} & 0   &     \\
B &   & 0   & (1-a_1)/2 & 1-a_2               & 1/2 &     \\ \hline
\end{array}

From the table you can also notice that we chose $a_0 = 1/2$, $a_1 = 3/4$. Solving the recurrence will give us $$a_n = \frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n}}+4\right)$$ which converges to $a = 2/3$.

So, if we repeat pouring from cup $2$ to cup $3$ and from cup $3$ to cup $2$ countably many times, we will end up with situation like this:

\begin{array}{ c | c | c  c  c  c }
\text{Drink} & \text{Step} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ \hline
A & \omega & 0 & 2/3 & 1/3 & 0   \\
B &        & 0 & 1/3 & 1/6 & 1/2 \\ \hline
\end{array}

A quick explanation. It doesn't matter if the full cup is $2$ or $3$. Passing to infinitely many steps, we lose track of this. So just say that the full cup is $2$. So, what's in the cup $3$? Well, we do know that cup $1$ is empty, and the state of cup $4$ the whole time. So just calculate what's in the cup $3$ from the total amount of drinks. Also note that if we repeated pouring from cup $2$ to cup $3$, they would just switch places (which should be obvious since we took a limit and $\lim_n a_n = \lim_n a_{n+1}$.)

Finally, pour from cup $2$ to cup $4$ and then from cup $4$ to cup $3$:

\begin{array}{ c | c | c  c  c  c }
\text{Drink} & \text{Step} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ \hline
A & \omega   & 0 & 4/6 & 2/6 & 0   \\
B &          & 0 & 2/6 & 1/6 & 3/6 \\ \hline
A & \omega+1 & 0 & 2/6 & 2/6 & 2/6  \\
B &          & 0 & 1/6 & 1/6 & 4/6 \\ \hline
A & \omega+2 & 0 & 2/6 & 3/6 & 2/6   \\
B &          & 0 & 1/6 & 3/6 & 2/6 \\ \hline
\end{array}

and have your celebratory drink from cup $3$.

Comment: Could this problem be solved in finitely many steps if there were 2 persons and each one had to drink a half cup of each drink?

Comment: @idiotas000, I don't see how that changes the problem, really. Seems to me to be equivalent because if you can solve your new problem, you automatically solved the original one, and if you solve the original one, give what's left to the other person. Also, I'm not claiming that there is no solution in finitely many steps, just that I don't know how to do it. It only looks to me that there might not be just using mixing strategy, but maybe there's something else that I didn't take account of, like drinking in several turns. Or spilling some of the drinks.

Answer (score 0):

Take two glasses and empty them into the other two glasses. You now have two completely full glasses. Drink half of each.

Comment: How would you know when you drank half?

Comment: @idiotas000 Then take half of one into one of the empty glasses, and half of the other into the other empty glass. Which is to say, fill them up to the level they were at before. Then drink.